# Remove single quotes from string in bash script

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose

I want to use the value of a string variable in Bash script in a `docker-compose` command. But whenever I do that, it prints the value surrounded with single quotes, thereby failing to run the `docker-compose` command.

I tried using `jq var | tr -d '"'`, but this didn't work. Here's my string variable and `docker-compose` command in a bash script:

```sh
var="--profile mongo"
docker-compose "${var}" up --abort-on-container-exit
```

On executing this script, it outputs:

```sh
+ docker-compose '--profile mongo ' up --abort-on-container-exit
```

And then exits out by showing bunch of commands that I can probably use. Is there a way to get rid of the single quotes?

Comment: this looks like one of those situations where you do **not** wrap `${var}` in double quotes; try `docker-compose ${var} up --abort-on-container-exit` ==> `+ docker-compose --profile mongo up --abort-on-container-exit`

Comment: The "proper" solution is to use an array: `var=(--profile mongo)` and then `docker-compose "${var[@]}"` so you don't have unquoted expansions.

Comment: See [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050), and specifically [5. I'm constructing a command based on information that is only known at run time](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050#I.27m_constructing_a_command_based_on_information_that_is_only_known_at_run_time)

Comment: hi Benjamin, thank you for providing your solution - this worked for me!

Answer (score 4):

> I want to use the value of a string variable in bash script in a docker-compose command.

No, you only think you want that.

> But whenever I do, it prints the value surrounded with single quotes, thereby failing to run the docker-compose command.

You appear to be presenting the output of bash running the script with `set -x` in effect (perhaps not manually -- your tools could be doing that for you).  This shows, as bash runs, how bash is *interpreting* each line of the script.  In particular, the single quotes show that the contents of your variable are being interpreted as a single word, not two.  Again, those quotes are emitted because that's how bash is interpreting the script, not the other way around.

> Is there a way to get rid of the single quotes?

Those quotes are a symptom, not the problem.  You get rid of them by solving the underlying problem.  Bash is interpreting the script that way because by quoting the expansion of `var` (as `"${var}"`), you have specifically requested that it do so.  That is, in fact, among the usual purposes of quoting variable expansions.  Since instead you want the expansion to be subject to word splitting, the first thing you might think of doing is just dropping the quotes:

```
var="--profile mongo"
docker-compose ${var} up --abort-on-container-exit
```

That will do the trick for your particular example, but it will break on a plenty of other, similar examples.  Much better would be to use a form that stores the multiple separate words *as* separate words.  In bash and other shells supporting arrays, the solution is to use an array, with each word in its own array element:

```
var=(--profile mongo)
docker-compose "${var[@]}" up --abort-on-container-exit
```

Note well the choice of `${var[@]}` to emit the elements, as opposed to `${var[*]}`.  The main difference between these two is that when the former is expanded inside double quotes, each element becomes a separate word, whereas when the latter is expanded in such a context, the result is always exactly one word.